# Solid State Electronics: Depletion vs Space-Charge region, what's the difference?

Tags: charge, solid-state-devices

I'm studying Solid State Electronics (can't make much of it) but I was wandering what is the difference between **space-charge** region and **depletion** region in a diode or in a BJT or in a MOSFET. Are they the same thing? If not, can you give an example of how space-charge region is formed?

Comment: From wikipedia:
_In semiconductor physics, the depletion region, also called depletion layer, depletion zone, junction region, space charge region or space charge layer_

Comment: Is wikipedia reliable on this topic? Then why make a fuss and call them differently, if they indicate the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each depletion region can be called space-charge region, but not all space-charge regions are formed due to depletion.

Space charge region = there is some surface area or volume where charge integral is not zero. In other words, there is some net charge present in this area or volume. Space charge regions can be formed due to various effects, including depletion effect.

However, in literature on semiconductors physics, space charge region usually refers to depletion region (I can't remember seeing any exceptions).

It is a good question by the way - it shows that you're really trying to understand the physical meaning of these terms.

Comment: Nice explanation! Makes sense for me now :)